# How to autorefresh only one form field in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

How to autorefresh / reload one part of wordpress site. Example: I need to autoreload one field in form every 1000 ms?

I have this shortcode in one gravity form field:

```
<?php

 function displaydate(){
     return date('g:i:s');
}
add_shortcode( 'date', 'displaydate' );
```

[date]

It shows current time but it does not reload so it does not show current time but time when page was loaded.

I need to reload this field but only this field, not the whole page.

Comment: ajax call on a timer, or just js as its simply the date

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This JS snippet will update your time form field every second using the format you specified (hh:mm:ss).  This will run in the client browser, so you won't need the shortcode or a page refresh.

```js
var nowFn = setupNowFn('time', false);
nowFn(); //call immediately
setInterval(nowFn, 1000); //call again every sec

function setupNowFn(id, militaryTime) {
  return function setNow() {
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var mins = ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    var secs = ('0' + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
    
    if(!militaryTime) {
      hours = hours % 12;
      hours = (hours)? hours : 12;
    }
   
    hours = ('0' + hours).slice(-2);
    var now = hours + ':' + mins + ':' + secs;
    document.getElementById(id).value = now; 
  };
}
```

```html
<input id="time" type="text"/>
```